# Camel access prevRouteContext at aggregationStrategy

Tags: reflection, error-handling, apache-camel

We need a generic way of handling exceptions/errors/bad responses from outgoing http calls in camel multicast subroutes by checking which route failed and at error handler dynamically - **.toD("routeId)** - send back an exchange with the same content to that route periodically until success. I went thru the accessible methods/fields of the Exchange object at aggregation and the only usable object from properties seems to be "CamelStreamCacheUnitOfWork" which has a field "prevRouteContext" which stores the route id of the multicasted route e.g. "direct:cancel-item":

```
.multicast().aggregationStrategy(new MyAggregationStrategy())
 ... other routes...
 .to("direct:cancel-item"); <-- exception happens inside this route
```

Problem: there is no public getter on this field but it would be very useful however there are push/pop methods but they are changing the order of contexts so it it not safe to use. Question: is it safe to use reflection to access the "routeId" of the previous context?

```
public class MyAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {

    @Override
    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
        DefaultUnitOfWork camelStreamCacheUnitOfWork = newExchange.getProperty("CamelStreamCacheUnitOfWork", DefaultUnitOfWork.class);
            if (newExchange.isFailed() || otherCustomErrors) {
                Field field = camelStreamCacheUnitOfWork.getClass().getDeclaredField("prevRouteContext");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                RouteContext value = (RouteContext)field.get(camelStreamCacheUnitOfWork);
                String id = value.getRoute().getId();
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found a solution to find out what was the current route executed by the multicast:

```
RouteDefinition multicastCallerRoute = (RouteDefinition) newExchange.getProperty("CamelStreamCacheUnitOfWork", DefaultUnitOfWork.class).getRouteContext().getRoute();
MulticastDefinition multicast = (MulticastDefinition) multicastCallerRoute.getOutputs().stream().filter(pd -> pd instanceof MulticastDefinition).findFirst().orElse(null);
if(multicast != null) {
    ToDefinition actualTo = (ToDefinition) multicast.getOutputs().get(newExchange.getProperty("CamelMulticastIndex", Integer.class));
    String actualToUri = actualTo.getUri();
}
```